# Куммулятивное суммирование с циклом

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных, суммирование

Столкнулась с такой проблемой. На картинке есть столбец `new_column`, в котором появляется единица тогда, когда в столбце `period_id` разрывается последовательность.

Мне нужно создать еще один столбец, в котором будет последовательно пронумеровано кол-во периодов, которые находятся в интервале от одной единицы до другой. Т.е. 0,1,2,3...15, затем нумерация видит единицу и начинается заново (0,1) и т.д.

[image]

Вопрос, можно ли с помощью функции cumsum прописать эту задачу?

Пробовала через суммирование только нулей, но не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы при появлении нового нуля после единицы, нумерация начиналась заново.

```
df['final'] = df['new_column'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данную задачу можно решить векторизированными (т.е. не прибегая к циклам) средствами Pandas.

Пример:

```
n [229]: df
Out[229]:
   new_column
0           1
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           0
5           1
6           1

In [230]: df["res"] = \
              df.groupby(df["new_column"].eq(1).cumsum())["new_column"].cumcount()

In [231]: df
Out[231]:
   new_column  res
0           1    0
1           0    1
2           0    2
3           1    0
4           0    1
5           1    0
6           1    0
```

Comment: Элегантно! Я всю голову сломал, не знал, что есть `cumcount` )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ЕМНИП он существует только для GropBy объектов

Comment: Ну, `groupby` тут конечно напрашивался, но дальше я не догадался )

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень крутое решение!)